Cannot read properties of null (reading 'collection'), this error is coming when submitting form. Unable to store data in database
in connection.js

const mongoClient=require('mongodb').MongoClient
const state={
    db:null
}
module.exports.connect=function (done){
    const url='mongodb://localhost:27017/'
    const dbname='shopping'

   mongoClient.connect(url,(err,data)=>{
     if(err) return done(err)
       state.db=data.db(dbname)   
    })
   done()
}
module.exports.get=()=>state.db

in product-helpers
var db=require('../config/connection')

module.exports={

    addProduct:(product,callback)=>{
        console.log(product)
        db.get().collection('product').insertOne(product).then((data)=>{
            console.log(data);
            callback(true)
       })
            
        
        
    }
}

I am unable to find what's the error. I am new to nodejs.
I tried to submit a form but not working. How can I fix this.

db.get().collection('product') is the only place in the shown code where you try to access a collection property or method, so that means db.get() did not return what you expected it to, but only null.

@Shahun , I have posted my answer.Please check and let me know in case if you have any query regarding the issue you are facing.

You cannot use module.exports to export multiple parts( i.e function ,object ,properties) from the same module .You should use only exports keyword to export more than one properties from a single module.
I have answered a same question here on this platform where I described in details how to create connection with database and get the DB-name using mongodb driver.
You will also get a crystal clear idea about how to import the module to get the database instance in your others module.
Please check the link below. I am sure you will get you answer there.
Node.js Express application not logging MongoDB connection status

This one worked perfectly. Thank you.

Welcome you are. I am glad to help you.
